# Sorting a list of nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have something like

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rick",
    "marks": [
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "score": 5
      },
      {
        "name": "Physics",
        "score": 8
      },
      {
        "name": "Computers",
        "score": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "marks": [
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "score": 6
      },
      {
        "name": "Physics",
        "score": 8
      },
      {
        "name": "Computers",
        "score": 7
      },
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Pamela",
    "marks": [
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "score": 7
      },
      {
        "name": "Physics",
        "score": 7
      },
      {
        "name": "Computers",
        "score": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "David",
    "marks": [
      {
        "name": "Maths",
        "score": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "Physics",
        "score": 9
      },
      {
        "name": "Computers",
        "score": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  
]
```

And would need to have :

```
[
  {
    'name': 'David',
    'marks': [
      {
        'score': 4,
        'name': 'Maths'
      },
      {
        'score': 9,
        'name': 'Physics'
      },
      {
        'score': 9,
        'name': 'Computers'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'Pamela',
    'marks': [
      {
        'score': 7,
        'name': 'Maths'
      },
      {
        'score': 7,
        'name': 'Physics'
      },
      {
        'score': 9,
        'name': 'Computers'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'Alice',
    'marks': [
      {
        'score': 6,
        'name': 'Maths'
      },
      {
        'score': 8,
        'name': 'Physics'
      },
      {
        'score': 7,
        'name': 'Computers'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'Rick',
    'marks': [
      {
        'score': 5,
        'name': 'Maths'
      },
      {
        'score': 8,
        'name': 'Physics'
      },
      {
        'score': 7,
        'name': 'Computers'
      }
    ]
  },
  
]
```

Note: Students should be sorted by the highest marks got in all the subjects. Total marks should not consider.
Example Pamela has received total 23 Marks and David has recived 22 Marks but David is in the 1st position because only David has got 9 marks in 2 subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`sorted(grades, key = lambda x: sorted([m['score'] for m in x['marks']], reverse=True), reverse = True)`

Where `grades` is your list of dictionaries. With [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) you can sort by a key.